# multiple sum in SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I work with PL/SQL developer. Behind this SQL statement I have SQL views.

From the code below, I receive charge for *FINE - 87* and for *FINR - 65*. My desire is to sum the result of **FINE** and **FINR** in another column.

Also I use number **0.12** for period 01/01/2013 - 01/03/2013, however I would like to use a different number for the period after 01/03/2013 (for instance **0.10**). My column for a time period is named timestamp (varchar).

Do you know how I can do these things?

```
select name_table_name, 
-- FINE, FINR 
case      
    when name_table_name in ('FINE','FINR') 
    and table_seconds <= table_balanced
    then (table_sd * 1.149798) - ((table_seconds/60)0.12)                          
    when name_table_name in ('FINE','FINR') 
        and table_seconds > table_balanced
    then (table_sd * 1.149798) - ((table_seconds/60)0.12)
    -- RUSN     
    when name_table_name = 'RUSN' 
    then (table_sd * 1.149798)-((table_seconds/60)*0.20)
else 0 end as charge
```

This is screen shot from the database. I would like the sum (156.66) of FINE and FINR to show in another column.

[image]

Comment: Your first 2 cases are doing the same thing, is there a reason why they are not combined in one case? `when name_table_name in ('FINE','FINR') then (table_sd * 1.149798) - ((table_seconds/60)0.12)`

Comment: _My desire is to sum the result of FINE and FINR in another column._ can you clarify more? if you want to sum them and also show each charge value separately. Then you need to do a subquery for one of them. If you need something else, plz elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
case
  when name_table_name in ('FINE','FINR')
  then 'FINE or FINR'
  when name_table_name = 'RUSN'
  then 'RUSN'
  else 'others'
end as name_table_name, 
sum (
case      
    when name_table_name in ('FINE','FINR') 
    and table_seconds <= table_balanced
    then (table_sd * 1.149798) - ((table_seconds/60)*0.12)                          
    when name_table_name in ('FINE','FINR') 
        and table_seconds > table_balanced
    then (table_sd * 1.149798) - ((table_seconds/60)*0.12)
    when name_table_name = 'RUSN' 
    then (table_sd * 1.149798)-((table_seconds/60)*0.20)
else 0 end) as charge
from table
group by 
case
  when name_table_name in ('FINE','FINR')
  then 'FINE or FINR'
  when name_table_name = 'RUSN'
  then 'RUSN'
  else 'others'
end;
```